# MATLAB code for an array consisting of matrices

Tags: matlab

I want to write MATLAB code that includes an array consisting of all $2 \times 2$ square matrices whose elements are elements of $\Bbb{Z}_2= \{0,1\}$, e.g.,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\quad \cdots$$

And how can I generalize the same thing with $\Bbb{Z}_2$ for $n \times n$ square matrix? Please help!

Comment: Use the 3rd dimension, i.e., use a $2 \times 2 \times 2^4$ matrix.

Answer (score 5):

You can start with

```
n = 2    
M = dec2bin(0:2^(n*n)-1,n*n)
```

then convert strings to matrices.

Comment: haha, very nice!! +1

Comment: @grixor- Can you tell me how to convert it into matrices.

Answer (score 3):

The MATLAB code below generates a $50 \times 50$ array in which each element is a random $100 \times 100$ square binary matrix. You can just change the parameters $n,I$ and $J$ as you wish.

```
n = 100;
I = 50;
J = 50;
M = [];
for j=1:J
    for i=1:I
       M{i,j} = round(rand(n,n));
    end
end
```

Comment: Please, why the downvote?